# Assigning value of an item in an array gives Bound value in a conditional binding must be an Optional type

Tags: swift

I am getting a compile error saying

```
Bound value in a conditional binding must be an Optional type
```

Below is a screenshot of the code

[image]

Comment: Please post your codes here instead of screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the value of array[index] to an Optional doing something like this:

```
if let value = Int?(array[index]){
    result += value
}
```

That's if your array contains Ints. You could also use AnyObject?, but you'll get a warning from xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The `array` should be declared as `Optional type`, take `Int?[]` as an example,

```
let array:Int?[] = [nil, 2, 3]
let index = 0
let count = array.count

for index in 0..count {
    if let value = array[index] {
        println(value)
    } else {
        println("no value")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the type of the value of array[index] is of optional, you could simple do like this:

```
if let value = array[index]{
 result += value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the compiler is complaining because array *isn't* a collection of Optional (nil-able) types. If it truly doesn't need to be, you don't actually need that `if`, since everything inside the array is guaranteed to be the same type, and that `if` statement won't protect you from a out-of-bounds error anyway. So just go with:

```
while ++index < length {
    result += array[index]
}
```

or perhaps better:

```
for value in array {
    result += value
}
```

or even better:

```
result = array.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```